# Struts 1 with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, jsp, struts-1, resourcebundle

I have a frontend JSP that does this:

```
<label>{{metadata[key].displayName}}:</label>
```

this works and displays the value

However, that value is really a "key" to an `ApplicationResource` defined in the Struts 1 framework.  So, ultimately, I want to do something like this

```
<label><bean:message key="{{metadata[key].displayName}}"/>:</label>,
```

but this does not work, and the error I get (in logs) is

```
Missing message for key '{{metadata[key].displayName}}'.
```

This means, that all configurations were OK, and the only issue is getting that
`{{metadata[key].displayName}}` properly into the "key" attribute of a struts-bean tag.

How can it be done?  The more complete code I have is here:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(key, val) in item" 
ng-if="metadata.hasOwnProperty(key)">
<div>
    
    <%-- <label>{{metadata[key].displayName}}:</label> --%>
    <label><bean:message key="<%={{key}}%>"/>:</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: JSPs are executed at server-side. Angular expressions are evaluated in the browser.

Comment: @JBNizet Message resources are server-side. That's right.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Struts1 with AngularJS @Dima?

Answer (score 0):

Angular works with the DOM, that already has been loaded by the browser. JSP is executed on the server side before the HTML is sent to the browser. If you can translate a message key at this stage then it will be rendered in resulting HTML where you can use its value to populate Angular model. And then bind its property to the view, which already should have translated value.

On the other hand if you can't map a key to the value on the server side, you still have a choice to get translated value for the key sent as parameter to another action. It's not recommended way to make much xhr requests to the server just for returning the translated value. However if your action will return JSON object, then it could be adopted with angular model.